# Redundant links in [site]/help/asking

Tags: bug, help-center, graduating-sites

I haven't checked on every graduated site but both Super User and Stack Overflow have a redundant link in the site "Asking" help centre page ([site]/help/asking):

On both these sites there is a link to "How to Ask Questions in Private Beta" which resolves to https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask-beta and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask-beta respectively.

Clearly these links are no longer needed on graduated sites and should be removed.

Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking and https://superuser.com/help/asking and remove those links to private beta help pages.

I suspect that all the graduated [site]/help/asking pages need updating.